# EF6 merge entity from WebApi

Tags: c#, entity-framework, crud, entity-framework-6.1

I've been tasked with the glorious mission of modernizing a CRUD system (Ironic). I'm using EF 6.1.1 and WebApi. I send the Entity using a DTO (dynamic object for now will create a static type when all is working, will also make the calls `async`)

```
[HttpGet]
public dynamic Get(int id)
{
    var p = personRepository.Get(id);

    return new
    {
        p.PersonId,
        p.BirthYear,
        p.DeathYear,
        p.Comment,
        PersonNames = p.PersonNames.Select(pn => new { pn.PersonId, pn.PersonNameId, pn.NameTypeId, pn.Firstname, pn.Prefix, pn.Surname })
    };
}
```

I then update fields on the `Person` object or add/remove/update `PersonNames` collection using `Knockout` and `ko.mapping`

I post the result to this WebApi method

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]Person person)
{
    personRepository.Merge(person);
}
```

All the id's etc are correct, in `personRepository.Merge` i've tried

```
public void Merge(Person person)
{
    db.People.AddOrUpdate(person);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

This works for the fields directly on the personobject, but it does not work with add/remove/update on the `PersonNames`

Can I support this without writing manual merge code?

**Solution**
Ended up doing this

```
public void Merge(Person person)
{
    db.People.AddOrUpdate(person);
    var existingNames = db.PersonNames.Where(pn => pn.PersonId == person.PersonId).ToList();
    var deleted = existingNames.Where(pn => person.PersonNames.All(d => d.PersonNameId != pn.PersonNameId));
    db.PersonNames.RemoveRange(deleted);

    foreach (var name in person.PersonNames)
    {
        db.PersonNames.AddOrUpdate(name);
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: See http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/864

Comment: Strange that this has not been included yet, most systems are sadly CRUD systems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given you've mentioned this is a CRUD system this all looks sensible to me. I can't see how you can really avoid mapping from your DTO's back to your domain entities (e.g. Person)

I expect you've thought of it already, but how about removing as much boiler plate merge code as possible using something like AutoMapper? https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

Mapping does get complicated for navigational properties (i.e. mapping between an object graph of DTO's back to an object graph of entities). This link goes into far more detail than I can: http://rogeralsing.com/2013/12/01/why-mapping-dtos-to-entities-using-automapper-and-entityframework-is-horrible/

Comment: Thanks, I know about automapper, It's usable for Entity>DTO, but very dangerous the other way.

Comment: Also looked at Breeze, but I do not like its RIA approach (The queries are executed on the client).

Comment: Yeah - completely agree. Entity framework support for disconnected graphs of entities is lacking (e.g. compared to NHibernate). I usually just slice the service up into commands that operate on a specific part of the graph. Obviously no use to you for an existing application expecting full CRUD endpoints though. Good luck!

Comment: Just in case you haven't stumbled across it - it may be worth looking at GraphDiff ( https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff ). I've heard it mentioned a fair amount on SO but never actually used it. May have a play with GraphDiff + AutoMapper + EF later just to see how it works out.

Comment: I'm on a budget so I will have to check that out outside of the project,  but thanks.  For now I'll do it manually.  Yeah,  I mainly use CQRS myself but as you pointed out I'm stuck with CRUD.